# Why $E[X]=\sum_{x\in \mathcal D}x\mathbb P\{X=x\}$ from $\mathbb E[X]=\int_{\Omega }X d\mathbb P$?

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. Let $X$ a discrete r.v. and $\mathcal D$ s.t. $$\sum_{x\in \mathcal D}\mathbb P\{X=x\}=1.$$

Q1) I know that the expectation of $X$ is given by $$E[X]=\int_\Omega Xd\mathbb P.$$
From this, how can I get $$E[X]=\sum_{x\in \mathcal D}x\mathbb P\{X=x\} \ \ ?$$

Q2) Same question if $X$ is a r.v. continuous, haw can I get $$E[X]=\int_{\mathbb R}xf_X(x)dx,$$
where $f_X$ is the mass function of $X$.

Q3) Is a r.v. either continuous or discrete ? i.e. is there any other sort of r.v. ? (and thus an other formula for the expectation ?)

Comment: **Q1) and Q2) :** You need measure theory to answer to this question. In fact $\mathbb P$ is a measure on $\Omega $. And the proof use a standard argument of density of step functions in $L^1(\Omega ,\mathbb P)$.

Comment: For **Q3)**, every $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ can be uniquely decomposed into the sum of (1) an absolutely continuous measure, (2) a pure-point measure, and (3) a singular continuous measure. (See [*Lebesgue's decomposition theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem).) If the measure is the law of some random variable, then (1) corresponds to continuous RV, (2) corresponds to discrete RV, and (3) corresponds to singular RV. A quintessential example of (3) is the [*Cantor distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution).